# Can anyone help me in this python-if-else task?

Tags: python, if-statement

[Assignment image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoTyj.png)

```
import random

n = random.randint(1,100)
if (n % 2 != 0):
    print("Weird")
elif (n % 2 == 0 and n in range(2,5)):
    print("Not Weird")
elif (n % 2 == 0 and n in range(6,20)):
    print("Weird")
elif (n % 2 == 0 and n > 20):
    print("Not Weird")
```

Is there any problem with this code?

Comment: `range(2,5)` does not include 5.

Comment: `print('Weird' if n%2 or (not n%2 and n in range(6,21)) else 'Not Weird')` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your range checks are not tight, for example: `range(2, 5)` includes integers between `2` and `4`, but anyway there's an easier way to write it; try this:

```
import random    
n = random.randint(1,100)

if n % 2 != 0:
    print("Weird")
elif 2 <= n <= 5: # from this point on, the number can only be even
    print("Not Weird")
elif 6 <= n <= 20:
    print("Weird")
elif n > 20:
    print("Not Weird")
```

Or even better this, which is simpler and does the same:

```
if n % 2 != 0 or 6 <= n <= 20:
    print("Weird")
else:
    print("Not Weird")
```

Answer (score -1):

import random

```
n = random.randint(1,100)
print(n)
if (n % 2 != 0):
    print("Weird")
elif (n % 2 == 0 and n in range(2,5)):
    print("Not Weird")
elif (n % 2 == 0 and n in range(5,20)):
    print("Weird")
elif (n % 2 == 0 and n >= 20):
    print("Not Weird")
```

You were missing some range I have just updated code try it.